# Executing query from html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to select the content from my table that consist of 2 column: `Judul, Isi.`

```
<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="addnewpage.css"/</head>
<body>

<?php
$k = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ubm_2015");
$sql = "select * from proses;";
$h = mysqli_query($k, $sql);
$b = mysqli_fetch_array($h);
?>

<div id="box">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="gambar/arg.gif" height="50" width="200"/>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="current">Pages</div>
            <a href="contact.html"><div class="menu">Contact</div></a>
            <a href="user.html"><div class="menu">User</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="top">
            Welcome, admin
            <a href="login.html"><input type="submit" value="log out" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="head"><h1>Edit Pages</h1></div>
        <div id="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Judul : </label></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" name="judul" value="<?php echo $b['Judul']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Body : </label></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" name="isi" value="<?php echo $b['Isi']; ?> "/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Bahasa : </label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="ind">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="eng">English</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Parent : </label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="p">Parent</option>
                            <option value="sm">Sub-Menu</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="button">
            <input type="button" value="Send"/>
            <a href="page.html"><input type="button" value="Back"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But the input box display `<?php echo $b['Isi']; ?>` instead the content of the table.

**NB :**

> 1. I saved the html code in htdocs folder, which inside the xampp folder.
> 2. The format is html.
> 3. Database name : ubm_2015

Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: print your query result and check whether your query returns data or not

Comment: Change the file extension to `.php` - by default `.html` files wont we ran through the php interpreter

Comment: Yes it is. But very unusual.
http://postimg.org/image/hy9dpt7cp/9e43797a/

Comment: @Steve Just changed the extension. No effect...... :(

Comment: you have two ; in your select query. remove one and try.

Comment: @PriyaRajaram Just tried. No Effect :(

Comment: Have you installed PHP in your system ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar I'm not sure. But last time (approximately 2 months) i code something like this, it working perfectly without installing php. I Have Apache instead....

Comment: restart your xampp/wamp server and try again

Comment: @PriyaRajaram Done. No effect :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are accessing this file via webserver (not as file://, but http://). Your webserver must process your code as PHP code, not as HTML code. Try using a .php extension.

In your webserver configuration you'll have something similar to this:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

so the .php (and similar) files will be processed as PHP code.

Comment: I access it by double-click the file ._. or by click "Run with firefox" in notepad++

Comment: Ok. Then your browser is opening the file as HTML code. You must install a webserver in your computer. Try with [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html].

Comment: I have the XAMPP. And i've run the Apache and Mysql correctly.

Comment: Great! The difference is that, when you call the file as file://, the browser manages it as HTML, not as PHP.

Comment: Sorry for waste your time master :( i'm just third semester student. Thanks a lot1

Answer (score 1):

`.html` cannot understand php coding.

Either change the format of the file to `.php`, or use ajax.

With ajax

```
$.ajax({
     url:"php file path",
     data:{kry:value},
     success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
     } 
});
```

But usinh `.php` is the better solution.

Comment: Just changed the extension to .php
but still no effect. Do i have to change the first & last line to <?php and ?> ?

Comment: have you installed php on your machine??

Comment: I'm not sure. But last time (approximately 2 months) i code something like this, it working perfectly without installing php. I Have Apache instead.

Comment: replace the entire code with `<?php echo "Hello World!!"; ?>`, check what you get as output.

Comment: Nah, it's empty. No output at all .___.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I write <?php echo "Hello World!"; 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

and still no output. What happen? .__. (FYI, i'm a third semester student)

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  before echo and check once.

Comment: Please paste your full URL here. I want to see your URL. Like `http://localhost/MyProject/file.php` @Conan

Comment: @NanaPartykar Hey it works! i type localhost/proses.php and it works! the one i did before was double-click the file! Thank you!!!!

Comment: If you think, this answer helped you. Please tick this as correct answer. As it will help other USER to find it easily. Thank @Conan

Comment: @NanaPartykar where? .__, where i have to tick it?

Answer (score 0):

first option is change file to php format and run through the xampp
in the browser
localhost/{Your Folder Name}/index.php

```
        **OR**
```

You have to use jquery for that

write ur php code in separate php file

for eg:
**ajax_data.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['table'])&&$_POST['table']=='proses'){
 $k = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ubm_2015");
 $sql = "select * from proses;";
 $h = mysqli_query($k, $sql);
 $b = mysqli_fetch_array($h);
 echo json_encode($b);
 exit();
}
```

in the html file

add id attributes to the inputs
eg:-

```
<input  type="text" name="isi" id="isiid" />
```

use jquery for data retrieve and in the success method u can set values based on id attributes
eg:- in the proses table u have isi named column,u have to set it to id="isiid"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_data.php",
            dataType :'json',
            data: "table=proses",
            success: function(msg){
                $('#isiid').val(msg.isi);
            }
   });

});
```